# How to generate a probability tree by tree data structure in python?

Tags: python, data-structures, tree, probability

I want to make tree data structure where user should define the level of tree and the child of the tree. and the data comes form user input..so if the level is 2 and child is 2 and the child data is [head, tail]..this data is comes from user as the child is 2 user can input 2 data

```
                          head
                         /    \
                     head      tail
                     /  \     /    \
                  head tail head  tail
```

initially we can set the root value to head or tail. user can define the probability of the head or tail
so if the probability of head is 0.3 and tail is 0.7 output should be like

```
                              head
                          0.3/     \ 0.7
                          head       tail
                      0.3/  \0.7   0.3/ \0.7
                     head    tail   head  tail
```

**this is my code**

```
class Node:
def __init__(self, value=None, children=None):
    self.value = value
    self.children = children or []

# helper function to allow a quick view on the tree structure
def tolist(self):
    if self.children:
        return [self.value, [child.tolist() for child in self.children]]
    return self.value
def fulltree(event, outcome):
if event == 0:  # Leaf node
    return Node()
l=[]
for _ in range(outcome):
    c=fulltree(event-1, outcome)
    l.append(c)
# Recursion:
return Node(None,l)
```

*main*

```
event=int(input("enter number of event:"))
outcome=int(input("enter number of outcome"))
tree = fulltree(event, outcome)
```

*if event is 2 and outcome is 2 i get this output*

```
enter number of event:2
enter number of outcome3
None 
None None None 
None None None None None None None None None
```

Comment: Have you tried something by yourself?

Comment: i have made the tree data structure as user input level and child

Comment: Then please include that code in your question.